# How can I use user input to choose element in enum class - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I need to get the values ​​of an element from an enum class using user input with the same name as the element. And it's not working unless I cascade if statements.

I tried to get the element by creating a variable and using it to get the Dir but it didn't work that way

```
enum class Dir( val dx: Int = 0, val dy: Int = 0) {
    UP(0, -1), Down(0, 1), Left(-1,0), Right(1,0)
}

fun main(){
    val choice = readln()
    println(Dir.choice)
}
```

I expected to get the following result:

user input: Up

> (0, -1)

user input: Down

> (0, 1)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you looking for `println(Dir.valueOf(choice))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One of them is to use the built-in `valueOf()` function of the enum, that returns the `Dir` value with the name matching the string that you pass to `valueOf`:

```kotlin
Dir.valueOf("Down") == Dir.Down
```

But that is a bit brittle depending on where you get the input from. If during a refactoring you decide to rename a constant, you might break some user inputs.

A very neat example of that is the typo you made in the value `UP` (which is full uppercase). If you were to rename it to `Up`, users that input `UP` will start failing.

So you could instead add a property to your enum to represent the external name you expect, and write a function to find the enum value based on this external name:

```kotlin
enum class Dir(
    val cliName: String,
    val dx: Int = 0,
    val dy: Int = 0,
) {
    UP("up", 0, -1),
    Down("down", 0, 1),
    Left("left", -1, 0),
    Right("right", 1, 0);

    companion object {
        private valuesByCliName = values().associateBy { it.cliName }

        fun fromCliName(name: String): Dir = valuesByCliName[name]
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown direction '$name'")
    }
}
```